# gradle resource bundle properties EscapeUnicode: not working

Tags: gradle, unicode, escaping, properties-file

Gradle escape resource bundle .properties

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.EscapeUnicode

processResources {
   from '/path/resources'
   include '*.properties'
   filter (EscapeUnicode)
}
```

The escaped proeprties files are not correct. The properties file are in UTF-8 encoding. Need to specify

> encoding="UTF-8"

? how to specify encoding for the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are after is `filteringCharset`. It defines the encoding of the files when filters are used. Without this setting the system default encoding is used, so you should always specify it when using filters.

```
processResources {
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
}
```